# Remove the additional entries in grub

Tags: grub2, 13.04, bootloader, mbr

I was trying to get a dual-boot set up with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04. After installing Ubuntu, it wouldn't let me go back into Windows 8. So I ran boot-repair and it fixed it self. Now I have all these different entries under my grub menu. How do you remove the entries that are broken and only leave the ones that work? Here is the list of entries under my grub menu.

[image]